# Importing products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, csv

I have a number of questions regarding product import in Magento.

In dataflow profile:

1. How come I get an error that says the image does not exist if I try to change the SKU value of the product on the exported csv file and try to import it back? This error does not appear if I keep the value of the SKU as is. Is the product considered by Magento as a new product if you modify the SKU so it can't find the existing image?
2. Why isn't the product showing on my catalog in admin and frontend even though I got the notice that the record was successfully imported? I tried changing the name of one product on the csv and imported it thinking that it might have just overridden the existing product on the website but this doesn't seem to be the case as the product was not updated.

Additional Note: I've made sure to clear cache and reindex data after the import. Also, whenever I tried to import the image to /media/import even though it already exists in /media/catalog/product/folder/file.jpg when I change the SKU, the import seems to work fine.

Comment: try reindexing the products and clear cache

Comment: I did that already. Nothing was added or changed.

Comment: For new product you should keep SKU unique.  Image should be on root folder if your img field contains name example.jpg. if image name is 'image/example.jpg' then your image should in root/image/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set inventory Value for product you have uploaded.
2. Also check in configuration for out of Stock setting.

As these two values are needed for a product to bve displayed in front end.

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't show up in the admin side as well. Basically, magento says that the product was successfully imported but it's not there.

Comment: Check if its issue related to store id.

Comment: I need to clear out something that might be crucial. Imported products are considered new products so if there's an existing product with the same SKU as the product to be imported, then it wouldn't do anything to the csv. Is that right?

Comment: Sorry but I'm really confused. Do you mean that if it had the same SKU as another existing product, it will update the details of the product. Like if the product is named A and the product to be imported is B, then B will replace A?

Comment: Then something strange is going on. I've exported the same product and imported it with a different name and same SKU to see if the changes apply but the name didn't change to the latter.

Comment: Actually, I think you're right that it's a store issue. I checked the data profile for import and export, import points to Default Values, Export points to my international store. The import seems to work fine now. Thanks for your time.